# Google App Engine Bulkloader “Authentication Failed”

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, bulkloader

I'm trying to use the bulkloader to load my data to the App-Engine server. I run the following command using Python 2.5:-

```
appcfg.py upload_data --application=myappname --kind=mykind    
--filename=data_archive.csv --url=http://myappname.appspot.com/remote_api
```

But its failing with this Authentication error:-

```
[INFO    ] Connecting to myappname.appspot.com/remote_api
[ERROR   ] Exception during authentication
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could 
be made because the target machine actively refused it>
[INFO    ] Authentication Failed
```

My idea is to do a bulk download from my development server and then use this dump to do a upload to the app-engine server. The bulk download worked fine. I used this format for this:-

```
appcfg.py download_data --application=myappname --kind=mykind 
--url=http://localhost:8888/remote_api --filename=data_archive.csv
```

But the bulk upoad fails. A couple of things: the bulk download asked me for a userid and password, but the bulk upload does not. Also, I don't currently have a app.yaml file which I see mentioned a lot - do I need one to do this ?

Thanks in advance for any help.
M.

**EDIT**
For anyone else struggling with this, the problem was indeed being behind the proxy server, but there was another 'error' with what is above. The app-id needs the "s~" bit added to it.

```
appcfg.py upload_data --application=s~myappname --kind=mykind
--filename=data_archive.csv --url=http://myappname.appspot.com/remote_api
```

Comment: This isn't an authentication issue - that message is a red-herring - your machine is unable to contact the App Engine app at all. Do you have a proxy you need to transit through in order to make external connections?

Comment: Nick, you are absolutely correct. When running without the proxy it runs fine. Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an authentication issue - that message is a red-herring - your machine is unable to contact the App Engine app at all. Do you have a proxy you need to transit through in order to make external connections?

Answer (score 0):

app.yaml is how it finds your server. I am not sure how you can try and upload without one.

In addition to having an app.yaml that points to the production server, the production server also needs to have remote_api turned on (in it's app.yaml and in the version you are trying to reach):

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

Comment: It apparently can run okay without a app.yaml. I was just stuck making the connection from behind a proxy. Thanks anyway. M.

Comment: +1 for Nick then. Ahh, I see you are specifying the application name on the command line. I tend to use the folder instead but that does require app.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need --application=s~myappname when using bulkloader - Google have mentioned before:

> Warning! Do not use the --application= flag to get the application ID
>   when using the bulk loader. Instead, use --url=.

For more detail take a look here: 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata